# rstudio crashes with shiny and reticulate

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to build a shiny app with a backend in python, using `reticulate` package.

The app is simple: user can upload a file in specific format and this action triggers some computation made in python.
The app is running fine, but when user upload file, the python computation is running fine but when displaying result

The log of Rstudio

> ERROR Parent terminated; LOGGED FROM: void
>   {anonymous}::detectParentTermination()
>   /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1239

My R version

```
platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "6.2"

$year
[1] "2019"

$month
[1] "12"

$day
[1] "12"

$`svn rev`
[1] "77560"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)"

$nickname
[1] "Dark and Stormy Night"
```

and I'm on ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: what is your Python code doing? Have you tested with just some dummy code that returns "hello world"?

Comment: Yes. Python code is fine, I can see from my log that the code ran correctly

Comment: Updating rstudio and using Software rendering options as indicated here solved the issue https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017886674-Troubleshooting-RStudio-Rendering-Errors